# How to treat rainwater for indoor use?

Tags: water, reuse, rain-harvesting

I'd like to maximize rainwater reuse in my household. I want to **wash the dishes** and **take a bath/shower** with the water, as well as supply a **washing machine** with it. [Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_rain#Human_health_effects), that acid rain is not dangerous for humans. Is physical particle filter enough for treatment? Is water collected from steel roof a problem, compared to water collected from extensive green roof?

Comment: What is a "green roof" ? I remove leaves, twigs, etc , and use rain water for aquariums and plants. I often get mosquito larva in my plastic storage barrel, big plus for aquariums.

Comment: I'm familiar with homemade 430 stainless-steel roof coverings. That's 0.028" thickness lateral-side-lapping strips with lateral attachment slots cut in it. Material flattening is not required until forming ridge shapes. Hold-downs are needed at the gable-ends. Or standing-seam panels could be formed with 0.015" thickness. The 430 is not painted and will not rust. Well, it will rust if touched with a cut-off disk but not rust if touched with a grinding wheel or if touched with a SS brush. I think I would use the water off the roof for toilet flushing.

Comment: The 430 roof covering lowers the house temperature during summertime. Or steel roofs are available with a granulated paint for the same purpose.

Comment: @blacksmith37, green roof is a roof with plants on it: [Green roof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_roof)

Comment: Often the problem is not the rain and how it is collected, but how the water is stored. A few years ago, clay water fountains were popular in the region where I live.  People with tendencies towards allergies often became sick drinking this water. Black mold growing between the clay particles was discovered to be the culprit.